# How can I select a SwiftUI Text view, or string, based on available space?

Tags: swiftui

For example, if my UI needed to display a length `Measurement` in human readable form, it might want to choose from one of the following formats to display one inch:

- 1"
- 1 in
- 1 inch
- one inch

So far I have tried:

- `truncationMode(_:)`: only accepts positional argument, no option for custom truncation
- `GeometryReader`: tells me what space is available (super useful!) but I don't see how to dynamically select a dynamically sized sub-view, seems to be optimized for generating fixed sized sub-views or overflowing the position

When I try to find another app that might have solved this problem it seems that they all rearrange the layout on orientation or other size change. I want to continue to have a single `HStack` of `Text` views that fit the space, keeping all the important information from being truncated when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define this View:

```
struct FlexibleTextView: View {
    let possibleTexts: [String]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Text(self.possibleTexts.last(where: { $0.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]).width < geometry.size.width }) ?? self.possibleTexts[0])
                .lineLimit(1)
        }
    }

    init(_ possibleTexts: [String]) {
        self.possibleTexts = possibleTexts.sorted {
            $0.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]).width < $1.size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]).width
        }
    }
}
```

When you init it, the possible texts are automatically sorted by their actual width. It takes the last one (so the one width the greatest width) where the width is smaller than the width of the container, which we get from GeometryReader. If even the first, so the smallest text is to big, (so `.last(where: { ... })` will return nil), we still use that first text, but you could also change this yourself to whatever you would like.

Here's an interactive example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var width: CGFloat = 80

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FlexibleTextView(["1\"", "1 in", "1 inch", "one inch"])
                .frame(width: width, height: 17)
                .border(Color.red)

            Slider(value: $width, in: 10 ... 80)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

With the slider, you can adjust the width to see the effect.

Comment: Not an issue for my use case, but I noticed that this solution mis-measures strings with Unicode escape sequences in them. So `"1\u{2033}"` is measured as longer than `"1″"` even though they print the same. Otherwise this is a great solution, thank you!

Comment: @DavidW.Keith Oh... that's a weird problem. I do not experience this; using 
`print("1″".size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]).width); 
print("1\u{2033}".size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]).width)` 
prints two times exactly the same. How did you discover this issue?

Comment: Luckily, there are also other ways to measure the actual width of a string, which you can find on the internet. I just took this one, because it was one of the easiest...

Comment: Just noticed it when I was playing with your example and I fixed the typography to use the double prime symbol. Not sure how I got into that state as I was playing around quite a bit to make sure all my edge cases were covered. Since Swift supports Unicode strings, I will just avoid using escaped strings for this view.